# comparison of projections in $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose p is a projection and $vv^*$ is a projection such that $vv^*\leq p\leq Cvv^*$,where $C$ is a constant,how to conclude that $p=vv^*$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $q\leq p\leq c q$, then 
$$
0=(1-q)(cq)(1-q)\geq(1-q)p(1-q)=[p(1-q)]^*p(1-q). 
$$
So $p(1-q)=0$. Thus $p=pq=qpq\leq q$, and so $p=q$.

Comment: Pro Aregerami,how to get $qpq\leq q$,I can only conclude that $qpq\geq qqq=q$?

Comment: You have $p\leq 1$.